# We can't get our 'expenses' shown in our spring/html project

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, spring-boot

We're having difficulties trying to figure out why our "expenses" doesn't show up in our webpage.
The expenses is a subclass to the superclass "rental", and we've written:

```
<td th:text="${expenses.rental_id}"></td>
```

We've also tried with:

```
 <td th:text="${rental.rental_id}"></td>
```

but none of the above works.

The error:

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "expenses.full_price" (template: "home/expenses" - line 54, col 9)

[It seems like it's here, the problem happen]

```
<td th:text="${expenses.rental_id}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.base_cost}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.rental_end_date}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.end_time}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.drop_off}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.drop_off_extra}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.km_end}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.repair_fee}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.fuel_level}"></td>
    <td th:text="${expenses.full_price}"></td>
    <td>
      <a th:href="@{'/updateExpenses/'+${expenses.rental_id}}">
        <button>Edit Expenses</button>
      </a>
```

[This is our homecontroller, we're using when getting the error]

```
@GetMapping("/expenses/{rental_id}")
    public String expenses(@PathVariable("rental_id") int rental_id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("expenses", expensesService.findExpensesById(rental_id));
        return "home/expenses";
    }
```

[The button that should send us to the page.]

```
<a th:href="@{'/expenses/'+${rental.rental_id}}">
                <button>Expenses</button>
            </a>
```

[The SQL statement we're trying to use.]

```
public Expenses findExpensesById(int rental_id){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE rental_id = ?";
        RowMapper<Expenses> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Expenses.class);
        Expenses e = template.queryForObject(sql, rowMapper, rental_id);
        return e;
    }
```

[We do have both getters and setters for full_price]

```
public double getFull_price(){
    return full_price;
}

public void setFull_price(double full_price) {
    this.full_price = full_price;
}
```

The field is called full_price everywhere. Even in the databasse.

private double full_price;

Comment: Hello ~  You should include code in your question,, not images of code. Read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15213361) to understand why.

Comment: Where is the code for `expenses` object? Are you sure it has `full_price` field and corresponding getter?

Comment: I doubt that there is a property named `full_price` I suspect it it named `fullPrice` with a `getFullPrice` method. If the field is named `full_price` make sure that there is a corresponding getter (as you left out the `Expenses` class that is impossible to answer).

Comment: We do have a getter and setter for the full_price. It looks like this:

   public double getFull_price(){
        return full_price;
    }

    public void setFull_price(double full_price) {
        this.full_price = full_price;
    }

Comment: Please add the code (the full code of the class) to your question, not as comments as that is unreadable.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: You only added a snippet, we need the full object. Another thing that helps is the full error stacktrace instead of just the snippet you have now.